# How do I get my NFT picture to show in Crossmint

Tags: credit-card, solana, nft, candy-machine, crossmint

I am using [www.crossmint.io](http://www.crossmint.io) to accept credit cards on my NFT drop.

For some reason, the image preview is showing a green leaf (crossmint logo) instead of my NFT collection image.

This is my code:

```
       <CrossmintPayButton
            collectionTitle="My Collection"
            collectionDescription="A collection of NFTs"
            collectionPhoto="/mint-preview.png"
            clientId="<REDACTED>"
        />
```

I am using version 0.15.alpha1.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You must enter an absolute URL in the `collectionPhoto` prop.

On addition, that URL must allow CORS.

With that the image preview for your NFT collection should work.[image: Example]